# Magento 2 make purchase order number optional

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, configuration

In Magento2 - Is there a way to make the purchase order number in the checkout optional? Currently it's a required field in 2.1.7 and I can't find a configuration setting to change it.

I'm aware that I could change it in the code somehow and just make it optional, but I'm afraid of a lot of problems and errors if the whole magento checkout expects a value of the number everywhere.

Comment: What is the `the purchase order number`?

Comment: the purchase order number is the "po_number" that must be entered on checkout with the payment method "purchase order"

Comment: @msblr have you got any solution?

Comment: Also looking at a similar situation.

Comment: solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274425/how-to-make-purchase-order-number-optional-in-checkout-page-magento-2-3